# Complex Inequality in the Plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on this problem:

Let $\alpha$ be a complex number with $0< |\alpha| < 1.$ Prove that the set of all $z$ such that $|z - \alpha| < |1 - \bar\alpha z|$ is the disc $z$ with $|z| < 1$.

I tried squaring both sides, and I got that $|z|^2 + |\alpha|^2 < 1 - |\alpha|^2 |z|^2$. I'm pretty sure that I'm most of the way there, but I can't get the last couple of steps in the proof.

Comment: probably you'll have to use the fact that $|\alpha|^2 = \alpha\bar{\alpha}$

Comment: Could you give me some additional information? I don't see how I can apply that to the problem.

Comment: No don't know how to solve it. But you are given the conjugate so probably you need to apply this!

Comment: Hint: Separate out $|z|^2$.  And check your signs on the RHS.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I didn't see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:
$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
|z - \alpha| < |1 - \bar\alpha z| & \iff (z-\alpha)(\bar z - \bar \alpha) \lt (1 - \bar\alpha z)(1 - \alpha \bar z) \\
 & \iff z \bar z - \cancel{z \bar \alpha} - \bcancel{\alpha \bar z} + \alpha \bar \alpha \lt 1  - \bcancel{\alpha \bar z} - \cancel{z \bar \alpha} + \alpha \bar \alpha z \bar z \\
 & \iff |z|^2(1 - |\alpha|^2) \lt 1 - |\alpha|^2 \\
 & \iff |z|^2 \lt 1
\end{align}
$$

The error in your proof attempt is here, you got the sign wrong on the RHS (it's $+|\alpha|^2|z|^2$):

> I tried squaring both sides, and I got that $|z|^2 + |\alpha|^2 < 1 - |\alpha|^2 |z|^2$

Comment: I know that. When I squared it, I cancelled, the $2Re(\bar \alpha z)$ from both sides.

Comment: @RealMath Right, thanks. I corrected the respective comment.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for correcting it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=x+iy$ and $\alpha=a+ib$, substitute these into the equation. Now totally cheat & get reduce to do the algebra ...
[image]

The first factor is non zero by hypothesis. So the second factor is less than zero.